# Mysql update fails, with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

I'm having trouble with an update query. So here's the deal.

I have 2 tables, `Article` and `Articleredefenition`.

In `Article`, I want to add the prices from `Articleredefenition`, however I fail to complete it.
I also want to add the products from id 300 until 620 and when there's no price filled in in the table of article

```
update Article
set Article.Price = (
select b.price
from ArticleRedefinition b, Article
where Article.ArticleId = b.ArticleId and  b.ArticleId > 300 and Article.ArticleId < 620
  and Article.Price is NULL and b.ConfigurationId = 27 )
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What is the error? Please paste here. I want to know whether it is syntax error or logic error

Comment: You should paste the error here as well. Maybe your subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: are you sure, that you subquery returns single result? if not, you can't do it this way, because only one row in subquery expected.

Comment: No I get multiple results, so that's basicly the problem I get.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE Article a 
    INNER JOIN ArticleRedefinition b 
    ON a.ArticleId = b.ArticleId 
    SET a.Price = b.Price 
    WHERE a.Price is NULL 
    AND (a.ArticleId BETWEEN 300 AND 620)
```

Thanks

Comment: M3ghana I get this error now with your solution: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Comment: That error might be because of the fieldnames. Please check whether the field names(column names) are proper in the query or not.

Comment: I get the error at the first line , so at: update Article a
It's at the 'a' that I get the error, all the fieldnames are correct